# php include file not found error

Tags: php, get, include

I have a question. I have this script

```
<?php
$GetPage= "index";
if((isset($_GET["page"])==true) && ($_GET["page"] != "")){
$GetPage = $_GET["page"];
}
?>
```

But I search on stackoverflow and google. But I can't find it. I want to include a error page when php can't find the file. How can I do that? I'm jut a starter with php.

Ow almost forgoten. I use this to include a part of my site:

```
<?php include ("include/$GetPage.php"); ?>
```

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Are you redundant to write `index.php` straight away in your include syntax?

Comment: do **NOT** do this. This is a hideously BAD security issue. A malicious user can include **ANY** file on your system for which they know the path. e.g. consider `http://example.com?page=../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability

Comment: Sorry @MarcB I didnt know that.

Comment: @Mr.Alien The first part of my question (the get script) is in my header. The ohter is lower in the file. I only use a index.php If thats what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

//file_exists will eliminate the need for any of your other checks.
if(file_exists($_GET["page"])){
    //Set the page to be loaded if it is found on the server
    $GetPage = $_GET["page"];
}else{
    //Show the user a 404 error message
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    //OR
    //Set the page to be loaded as your custom error page
    $GetPage = "my_error_page.php";
}

//Include the page
include $GetPage;

?>
```

Are you looking for a 404 redirect? Or just load a custom error page into the  document? Select the above based on what you wish to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

This is a good begin. But the script I have include when i don't use the get function a file. That is something that I need for this site. But I'm a beginner and someone helpt me with the script i posted. But it needs a small update.

Comment: As stated by @CooPer, you should also escape the passed variable to prevent any kind of injection.

Comment: Were you able to accomplish what you were looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$GetPage = $_GET["page"];  // validate string!!  
if (!file_exists('include/' . $GetPage . '.php')) {
    $GetPage = 'errorPage';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But it forgot to post something.
I use the $getpage to include my - home - page. 
The ohter part i use to include the files. When i make a typo or a user i get a php error like this:

Warning: include(include/about0.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tombalf/domains/tombalfoort.com/public_html/index.php on line 59

I dont want that php error but a error that i made.

Answer (score 0):

first check file is in folder (for injection) , (`$file` is full path of file.)

```
$path = "include";//your include folder path
if ( substr(realpath($file) , 0,strlen($path)) != $path || is_dir($file))
        //error file not found
```

second check file is exist or not

```
if (!file_exists($file))
//error
```